# F. Schubert "Mut!", Number in front of piano-staff

Tags: piano, notation

[image]

I'm currently transcribing this passage from *F. Schubert's* "**Mut**".
Can anyone tell me why the piano-staff is named "*42.*"?

Comment: Current guess I can't verify: This sheet music is not from the beginning of the book, and this song is the 42nd piece in the book.

Comment: Courage, be brave! Could the previous piece be labelled '41'. Pretty sure it's not the answer to Life, the Universe and Everything... Although, actually, it is!

Comment: I can't verify it either because I'm working on a copy and not the complete book, so I can't just look it up, but I think I remember that it was a collection of 45 songs, so you're probably right.
Thank You

Comment: @Tim  I am absolutely in agreement

Comment: {Lewis Caroll alert!}  The piano staff is actually **numbered** 42.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Mut" is the twenty-second *Lied* ("song" in German) of Schubert's song cycle *Winterreise*.

*Winterreise* was Schubert's second song cycle, after *Die schöne Müllerin* of a few years earlier.

Scores typically combine these two sets (along with some other songs), so it seems that this score numbered the songs together: with twenty songs in *Die schöne Müllerin*, and since "Mut" is the twenty-second in *Winterreise*, this score has it labelled as number 42.